# C# Threading in real-world apps

Tags: c#, multithreading, codeplex

Learning about threading is fascinating no doubt and there are some really good resources to do that. But, my question is threading applied explicitly either as part of design or development in real-world applications.

I have worked on some extensively used and well-architected .NET apps in C# but found no trace of explicit usage.Is there no real need due to this being managed by CLR or is there any specific reason?

Also, any example of threading coded in widely used .NET apps. in Codelplex or Gooogle Code are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That entirely depends on the application.

For a *client* app that ever needs to do any significant work (or perform other potentially long-running tasks, such as making web service calls) I'd expect background threads to be used. This could be achieved via `BackgroundWorker`, explicit use of the thread pool, explicit use of Parallel Extensions, or creating new threads explicitly.

Web services and web applications are somewhat less likely to create their own threads, in my experience. You're more likely to effectively treat each request as having a separate thread (even if ASP.NET moves it around internally) and perform everything synchronously. Of course there *are* web applications which either execute asynchronously or start threads for other reasons - but I'd say this comes up less often than in client apps.

Comment: Any example of such widely used client app. from Codeplex or Code?

Comment: @GilliVilla: Not that I know of off-hand. But look for client apps and they're likely to use threads somewhere...

Comment: To follow up: client apps can also use Reactive Extensions (which is nearing completion). Also, when Jon talks about web apps treating "each request as (*sic:has*) having a separate thread", that does include asynchronous pages as well.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest place to use threading is performing a long operation in a GUI while keeping the UI responsive.

If you perform the operation on the UI thread, the entire GUI will freeze until it finishes.  (Because it won't run a message loop)
By executing it on a background thread, the UI will remain responsive.

The `BackgroundWorker` class is very useful here.

Comment: Exactly, I use threads a lot for progress bars or heavy calculations so that the GUI doesn't freeze and become unresponsive.

Answer (score 4):

> is threading applied explicitly either as part of design or development in real-world applications.

In order to take full advantage of modern, multi-core systems, threading must be part of the design from the start.  While it's fairly easy (especially in .NET 4) to find small portions of code to thread, to get real scalability, you need to design your algorithms to handle being threaded, preferably at a "high level" in your code.  The earlier this is done in the design phases, the easier it is to properly build threading into an application.

> Is there no real need due to this being managed by CLR or is there any specific reason?

There is definitely a need.  Threading doesn't come for free - it must be added in by the developer.  The main reason this isn't found very often, especially in open source code, is really more a matter of difficulty.  Even using .NET 4, properly designing algorithms to thread in a scalable, safe manner is difficult.

Comment: +1 Threading definitely has to be part of design!!!! No question about that!   @Reed So does it mean it is dispensable due to difficulty? The reason I get boggled is even in non-opensource apps. which are mission critical Threading is avoided.

Comment: @Shankar: I, personally, don't feel that it's "dispensable" at all - modern development really should be using threading when appropriate, and it's very appropriate for (portions of) nearly every client side application.  That being said, it's often left out because of difficulty, even when it shouldn't be...  Threading does increase the maintenance cost of an application, but it's really required for usability.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a +1 on the Parallel Extensions to .NET. Microsoft has done some great work here to improve the ThreadPool. You used to have one global queue which handled all tasks, even if they were spawned from a worker thread. Now they have a lock-free global queue and local queues for each worker thread. That's a very nice improvement.

I'm not as big a fan of things like Parallel.For, Parallel.Foreach, and Parallel.Invoke (regions), as I believe they should be pure language extensions rather than class libraries. Obviously, I understand why we have this intermediate step, but it's inevitable for C# to gain language improvements for concurrency and it's equally inevitable that we'll have to go back and change our code to take advantage of it :-)

Overall, if you're looking at building concurrent apps in .NET, you owe it to yourself to research the heck out of the Parallel Extensions. I also think, given that this is a pretty nascent effort from Microsoft, you should be very vocal about what works for you and what doesn't, independent of what you perceive your own skill level to be with concurrency. Microsoft is definitely listening, but I don't think there are that many people yet using the Parallel Extensions. I was at VSLive Redmond yesterday and watched a session on this topic and continue to be impressed with the team working on this.

Disclosure: I used to be the Marketing Director for Visual Studio and am now at a startup called [Corensic](http://www.corensic.com) where we're building tools to detect bugs in concurrent apps.

Answer (score 1):

Most real-world usages of threading I've seen is to simply avoid blocking - UI, network, database calls, etc.

You might see it in use as `BeginXXX` and `EndXXX` method pairs, `delegate.BeginInvoke` calls, `Control.Invoke` calls.

Some systems I've seen, where threading would be a boon, actually use the isolation principle to achieve multiple "threads", in other words, split the work down into completely unrelated chunks and process them all independently of each other - "multi-threading" (or many-core utilisation) is automagically achieved by simply running all the processes at once.

I think it's fair to say you find a lot of stock-and-trade applications (data presentation) largely do not require massive parallisation, nor are they always able to be architected to be suitable for it.  The examples I've seen are all very specific problems.  This may attribute to why you've not seen any noticable implementations of it.

Answer (score 1):

The question of whether to make use of an explicit threading implementation is normally a design consideration as others have mentioned here.  Trying to implement concurrency as an afterthought usually requires a lot of radical and wholesale changes.

Keep in mind that simply throwing threads into an application doesn't inherently increase performance or speed, given that there is a cost in managing each thread, and also perhaps some memory overhead (not to mention, debugging it can be fun).

From my experience, the most common place to implement a threading design has been in Windows Services (background applications) and on applications which have had use case scenarios where a volume of work could be easily split up into smaller parcels of work (and handed off to threads to complete asynchronously).

As for examples, you could check out the [Microsoft Robotics Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20150515023119/http://www.microsoft.com/robotics) (as far as I know there's a [free version](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c185a802-5bbe-4f28-b448-aefe63a7eff7&displaylang=en) now) - it comes with an redistributable (I can't find it as a standalone download) of the [Concurrency and Coordination Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/microsoft-robotics/bb648752%28v=msdn.10%29), there's some coverage of it on Microsoft's [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/Concurrency-and-Coordination-Runtime/).

As mentioned by others the Parallel Extensions team ([blog is here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/)) have done some great work with thread safety and parallel execution and you can find some samples/examples on the [MSDN Code site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/).

Answer (score 0):

Threading is used in all sorts of scenarios, anything network based depends on threading, whether explicit (sockets stuff) or implicit (web services). Threading keeps UI responsive. And windows services having multiple parallel runs doing the same things in processing data working through queues that need to be processed.

Those are just the most common ones I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers reference long-running tasks in a GUI application.  Another very common usage scenario in my experience is Producer/Consumer queues.  We have many utility applications that have to perform web requests etc. often to large number of endpoints.  We use producer/consumer threading pattern (usually by integrating a custom thread pool) to allow high parallelization of these tasks.

In fact, at this very moment I am checking up on an application that uploads a 200MB file to 200 different FTP locations.  We use [SmartThreadPool](http://smartthreadpool.codeplex.com/) and run up to around 50 uploads in parallel, which allows the whole batch to complete in under one hour (as opposed to over 50 hours were it all uploads to happen consecutively - so in our usage we find almost straight linear improvements in time).

Answer (score 0):

As modern day programmers we love abstractions so we use threads by calling Async methods or BeginInvoke and by using things like BackgroundWorker or PFX in .Net 4.

Yet sometimes there is a need to do the threading yourself. For Example in a web app I built I have a mail queue that I add to from within the app and there is a background thread that sends the emails. If the thread notices that the queue is filling up faster that it is sending it creates another thread if it then sees that that thread is idle it kills it. This can be done with a higher level abstraction I guess but i did it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I can't resist the edge case -  in some applications where either a high degree of operational certainty must be achieved or a high degree of operational uncertainty must be tolerated, then threads and processes are considered from initial architecture design all the way through end delivery

Case 1 -  for systems that must achieve extremely high levels of operational reliability, three completely separate subsystems using three different mechanisms may be used in a voting architecture -  Spawn 3 threads/proceses across each of the voters, wait for them to conclude/die/be killed, and proceed IFF they all say the same thing  - example - complex avionic susystems

Case 2 -  for systems that must deal with a high degree of operational uncertainty -  do the same thing, but once something/anything gets back to you, kill off the stragglers and go forth with the best answer you got - example - complex intraday trading algorithms endeavoring to destroy the business that employ them  :-)